# Unable to load JSCS config file

Tags: gulp, jscs, gulp-jscs

I new in "Gulp". I see this error when I start task with use gulp-jscs (v3.0.0)

```
TypeError: Unable to load JSCS config file
Unable to load JSCS config file
    at Function.keys (native)
    at copyConfiguration (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/jscs/lib/config/configuration.js:1193:12)
    at NodeConfiguration.Configuration._processConfig (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/jscs/lib/config/configuration.js:474:5)
    at NodeConfiguration.Configuration.load (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/jscs/lib/config/configuration.js:238:10)
    at StringChecker.configure (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/jscs/lib/string-checker.js:67:29)
    at Checker.configure (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/jscs/lib/checker.js:28:39)
    at module.exports (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/gulp-jscs/index.js:17:11)
    at /home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/gulpfile.js:81:13
    at taskWrapper (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:300:12)
    at asyncRunner (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/async-done/index.js:36:18)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:389:13)
```

But if I install version ^3.0.2, I see

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'maxErrors' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/gulp-jscs/index.js:31:20)
    at /home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/gulpfile.js:81:13
    at taskWrapper (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:300:12)
    at asyncRunner (/home/nikolay/Завантаження/f/node_modules/async-done/index.js:36:18)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:389:13)
```